# Show different calculations in PivotTable value fields google sheet

Tags: google-sheets, pivot-table

i am trying to show % of differences in a pivot table on google sheet, but i cant find the way to do de same i do in excel

https://support.office.com/en-us/article/show-different-calculations-in-pivottable-value-fields-014d2777-baaf-480b-a32b-98431f48bfec

I simply have a value and what I want is the percentage of difference with the previous period, like this example in excel https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wdcMZ-FCb4g

thanks in advance

Comment: I'm sure there's a way to do it with a query() as opposed to a pivot table.  If you share a sample sheet I can take a look

Comment: yes! thanks ! https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1c1xLZ6XbrxfZbZ9oqiLXmE9fq_oxxsYAZJAIgKLRDdw/edit#gid=1821622363

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work at the top in D1 to get your rolling differences...

```
=ARRAYFORMULA({"diff.";IF((C2:C="")+(A2:A<>""),,C2:C-ARRAY_CONSTRAIN(C1:C,ROWS(C2:C),1))})
```